# React render prop - why is the function not called?

Tags: reactjs

I use a render prop in react (native). I want to pass a button from Parent to child where the onClick method from Button shoud be triggered from Child. I dont know what Im doing wrong but the function inside child is never called. I looked at examples but cant figure out whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Selector
                render={({handleSelect}) => {
                    return <Button
                        title="select"
                        handleSelect={handleSelect}
                    />

                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

```
const Child = ({render}) => {
    const handleSelect = (input) => {
        console.log("helllooo") //is never called
    };
    
    return (
        <View>
            {render({handleSelect: handleSelect})}
            <View><Text>other content here...</Text></View>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Comment: can you show some code of your <Button> component

Comment: there is none, its just a simple button from react native library. the button is being rendered fine, just that function is never called

Comment: oh im an idiot. of course it didnt work, since Button is not a component and i never called that function, i needed to switch it to onPress={handleSelect} (the native onclick eventhandler)) and it worked

Comment: Happens all the time in JavaScript , thats why typescript is better, btw i submitted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to pass handleSelect on onPress on Button component